# User.HasClaim does not successfully read claim properties in .NET Core 2.0 Web Api

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am having an issue when using the Authorize attribute with a Policy that I'm defining in Startup.cs. I edited my controller to manually check claims. I can see the claims including a scope claim with the correct scopes but when I manually check for that claim/scope it comes back as false. I'm using Azure AD B2C as my identity server and successfully get a validated token.

Here is code from my Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var policyRead = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", "vendor.read")
            .Build();
        options.AddPolicy("VendorRead", policyRead);

        var policyWrite = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", "vendor.write")
            .Build();
        options.AddPolicy("VendorWrite", policyWrite);
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }) 
        .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
        {
            jwtOptions.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"]}/v2.0/";
            jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
            jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"]}/v2.0/",
                ValidAudience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"]))
            };
            jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                OnTokenValidated = TokenValidated
            };
        });
```

Here is my controller code where I'm manually checking for claims:

```
// GET: api/Vendor/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(VendorRequest request)
{
    var hasClaim1 = User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "vendor.read");
    var hasClaim2 = User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "scope");
    var hasClaim3 = User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "scp");
    var hasClaim4 = User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope");
    var hasClaim5 = User.HasClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", "vendor.read");
    var hasClaim7= User.HasClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", "vendor.write");
    var allowed = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(User, "VendorRead");
    if (!allowed.Succeeded)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
    }
```

The only hasClaim that comes back as true is hasClaim4.

Here is what my claims look like:
[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I am only trying to get the vendor.read scope to work for now.

Comment: The debugger view seems to show that the scope claim does not contain an array of strings, but rather a string containing two scopes separated with a space. Could you try getting the claim value and then doing `value.Split(' ').Contains('vendor.read')`?

Comment: Yes, that works @juunas but I don't know how to write a Policy like that in my Startup.cs because I don't want to have to write it out manually like I have above in my controller. I want to use the decoration like Chris Pratt mentions below. Just to be clear this is the line that works: `var hasClaim8 = User.HasClaim(c => c.Type.Contains("scope") && c.Value.Contains("vendor.read"));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scope claim is a space delimited list so the [`RequireClaim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim?view=aspnetcore-2.0) helper will not work in this case but the more generic [`RequireAssertion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy) will.

**Example Scope Claim**

```
"scp": "demo.read demo.write user_impersonation Test-Value"
```

**Sample `RequireAssertion()`**

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ScopeCheck", policyBuilder => 
        policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(async handler =>
        {
            var scopeClaim = handler.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope");
            var scopes = scopeClaim?.Value.Split(' ');
            var hasScope = scopes?.Where(scope => scope == "demo.write").Any() ?? false;
            return hasScope;
        }));
});
```

**Sample `Controller`**

```
[Authorize("ScopeCheck")]
public class SecureController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok(new { Message = "You are allowed" });
    }
}
```

[Full Sample Project](https://spottedmahn.visualstudio.com/_git/Experiments?path=%2FScope%20Policy%20Requirement%2FScope%20Policy%20Requirement%2FStartup.cs&version=GBcode-formatting-in-pr&_a=contents) - [Sample token](https://jwt.ms/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.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.NtyPdeV-hxq3uZxMhf9k5_AYfQkOBVIiEGnukAwwkdV406DTjftTdngVmYOkte6cuYweCG9znDprH2DYnhQWXkBhxNKDJgI9MJZESDSoqleBIEvX6-Tnc1zSrggUBSSOTKgxUWC6TLlunqEOR4CYaaOOZA4KP65HuksUfN7oUpvV1TOxxkKuu7b_N5iBU9V0v7Fxmi2gUxhuAsCp-P52Hp0rBJBotgExOPSoJwmU48f-4Zt2sLx1wreGUE61JDZyfxV7myVTh6qkL0xo0FK1mqF30kKGQwwfx_8w83b-nHku39of54QsQUsY8XTRFOM6Z9nuYzWVXl9XhAAakUztog&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.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.eleKiaKDckywoN3rIDrhFo9UjnAYGon5O5_toDYs_WzyqTpZtvq6JIxwi54hhevVr6zKWN_5lWkuHh_F-VK_wF-dg3hkgBPPt8WQzuT7Y0e6GI03NZrebRz0KvD9Jm_uxFGa3W9_ciN1_WOE62Y7cuQSGCaeJWfshNfiheWiEfn4ugE2BY-TEV3gBfDL3GG8e33nQm94eBJac4GZdlrWXXsxWUy0xLFfMr3txSh5J--hxgiGE3RFW0Fm21WI4HR9Z70CN3jy_urdawx8JUx6VFVGE8EYQnGAuOtrdoOk--KwasVH7iFkWVL9t30DjfALYIEzyezZY7rNfPUiBIqagA)

---

> [Access Token Scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) (RFC 6749 section-3.3)

> The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-
> delimited, case-sensitive strings.  The strings are defined by the
> authorization server.  If the value contains multiple space-delimited
> strings, their order does not matter, and each string adds an
> additional access range to the requested scope

Comment: [RequireClaim Helper for Scope Claim?](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1760)

Comment: How about checking `scopeClaim.Issuer`?  Would that be more secure?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do to get it to work with the [Authorize("VendorRead")] attribute:

```
private Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext arg)
{
    var identity = arg.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var scopeClaims = identity?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Contains("scope"))?.Value.Split(' ').ToList();

    if (scopeClaims != null)
    { 
        foreach (var scope in scopeClaims)
        {
            identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("scope", scope));
        }
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

I added this method to the Startup.cs that gets called when the token is validated. You can see that wire up above when I define the JwtBearerEvents.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like `vendor.read` is actually the claim *value*, not type.

Also, FWIW, the whole point of setting up policies is so you don't have to do this type of manual validation. Simply decorate your action with:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "VendorRead")]
```

Comment: Right, I understand about the decoration, I was doing that to manually test and see what was going on. The decoration does not work either.

Comment: FYI, `vendor.read` is in the claim value but the claim value is a space-delimited list, not a single value.